# Confluent Kafka Replicator | Consumer group offsets not replicated to destination cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

**Update:**

> Found a workaround by setting fromBeginning: false for the consumer on the destination cluster. Not a best solution but it works...

For some reason all consumer group offsets not replicated to destination cluster. For example I started a consumer on source cluster with consumer group TEST (all messages are pulled) then I started a consumer (with consumer group TEST) on the same topic that was replicated into destination cluster, the result is that both consumers got all message.

I read about [consumer-offset-translation-feature](https://docs.confluent.io/current/multi-dc-deployments/replicator/replicator-failover.html#consumer-offset-translation-feature) but didn't made it work.

Consumer Config:

```
bootstrap.servers=sourceKafkaEndpoint:9092
interceptor.classes=io.confluent.connect.replicator.offsets.ConsumerTimestampsInterceptor
```

Producer Config:

```
bootstrap.servers=destKafkaEndpoint:9092
```

Replicator Config:

```
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.replicator.ReplicatorSourceConnector
auto.offset.reset=latest
topic.config.sync=false
config.action.reload=none
```

Executable Command:

```
replicator --consumer.config consumer.properties --producer.config producer.properties --replication.config replication.properties --topic.regex ".*" --cluster.id replicator
```

Kafka Info:

```
Source cluster Kafka version: 2.0.1-cp4
Destination cluster Kafka version: 2.4.1
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question and a lot of things have been change since I guess, but it's for the better because now Replicator is documented a lot better.

As explained [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-replicator/configuration_options.html#source-topics):

> Replicator will not copy the internal __consumer_offsets or
> __transaction_state topics from the source cluster even if matched in topic.regex. To copy these topics, list them in topic.whitelist.

This is because consumer group offsets are meaningless between clusters. You can not rely on them being identical. See my [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60935626/manually-setting-kafka-consumer-offset/63671655#63671655) for more detail.
The only reliable way to achieve such a task is using [offset translation via timestamp preservation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/multi-dc-deployments/replicator/replicator-failover.html#consumer-offset-translation-feature). It allows to translate `__consumer_offsets` to the destination cluster based on the message creation time from the source cluster.

Comment: Does this mean that offset are not replicated at all?, we just have those timestamps pointing to some offsets?

Comment: They are not "replicated", but "translated". Meaning you will have your  __consumer_offsets in destination cluster as per usual, but the values in that topic will not be identical to the ones in the source cluster.

Comment: But the commit of an offset in a datacenter will produce another commit of a translated-offset to the other datacenter based on the timestamp. Right?. So we should have "two" commits, one per datacenter. Is that correct?

Comment: The commit is nothing more than a record in __consumer_offsets topic that explains how far the consumer group is still lagging behind. It's the job of the replicator to translate and store that lag, consumers themselves do not write to 2 clusters simultaneously. It's only a failover mechanism, that is - "when one cluster is down, switch to the other one".